# HTTP Authentication popup doesn't shows up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load a snapshot of a camera and i want the authentication popup to show up when i click the button, but it doesn't work. i'm following this example https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/

The popup shows up when i go to http://192.168.100.103:8080/snapshot.jpg but it doesn't when i click on the button.

```html
<script type='text/javascript'> 
function getit() {setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('downloadImg').src = ('http://192.168.100.103:8080/snapshot.jpg?' + Math.random().toString(10));}, 1000);}
</script> 

<img id="downloadImg">

<input type="button" class="button1 buttonspace" value="Display Image" id="displayImage" onclick='getit()'>
```

Even though the code works when i sign in, i would like that the authentication popup shows up when i load the image.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does your webserver basic auth config look like? If it is on the Location /snapshot.jpg then your cache buster random might not have the desired effect since you have already input the password previously. What happens if you clear your basic auth passwords (you can do this with chrome://restart in chrome)

Comment: i'm using a private window to test it, https://puu.sh/D5FiA/0a0b18a98d.mp4
how do i check the auth config? i think i cant access the webserver of the camera. I'm playing around with a tplink NC200 camera

Comment: 401 : unauthorized - you can auth this way: `http://user:pass@192.168.100.103:8080/snapshot.jpg`

Comment: I understand now - this first time the src tag gets the image and that failes because it is unauthorised. Then you hit the image directly and the browser pops up auth window. The browser will not pop up auth window on a src tag will just fail with a 401 in the background as you see from your log.  As @GrafiCodeStudio mentions you can put the username and password into the url of the src tag. Can the image be hosted in a differen location so that it is not password protected. Maybe a tiny iframe with the image in it on you main page would cause the auth pop up

Comment: That works perfectly! thank you guys :).
```
<iframe id="downloadImg" src="">
```

Comment: Actually I don't think you need an iframe you could just have the image loaded on you page but hidden: <img src="http://192.168.100.103:8080/snapshot.jpg " height="0" width="0" >

Comment: apparently doesn't want to popup if i use an img, i can just hide the iframe. it works just like i wanted it. thank you again